# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'Graph' in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed networkx module for python in windows and tried running a simple program on it using vs code. But when tried to run it says "AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'Graph'". Not just Graph, if I use other networkx function it still says that networkx doesn't have that particular attribute. I face this problem in vs code only because when running it on IDLE it works fine. Please help

Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as p

G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.complete_graph(10)
nx.draw(G)
p.show()
```

Output:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:/Python programs/networkx.py", line 1, in <module>
    import networkx as nx
  File "c:\Python programs\networkx.py", line 4, in <module>
    G = nx.Graph()
 AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'Graph'
```

Comment: Your script is called ***networkx.py***. When `import networkx as nx`, it imports itself. Rename it to something that doesn't collide with an existing module name.

Comment: Don't name your file ``networkx.py``

Comment: Thanks, Mike Scotty, your trick works. But why is it creating the problem? Is there any restriction for naming the file similar to module name?

Comment: Thanks, CristiFati for help, it works now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't name your file same as a module. Change the name of your file from networkx to something else.